# Округление в Textbox?

Tags: c#, windows

Есть один калькулятор MBI, сейчас он выдаёт результат как "0,001408", например. Задача - округлять получаемый результат до вида "xx.x".
Как это сделать?
Код прилагаю

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MBI
{
    public partial class mainForm : Form
    {
        string weightToString;
        double height;
      double weight;
        double MBICalc;

        public mainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    private void heightBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        weightToString = heightBox.Text;
        height = Convert.ToDouble(weightToString);

    }

    private void weightBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        weightToString = weightBox.Text;
        weight = Convert.ToDouble(weightToString);
    }

    private void calculateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            MBICalc = weight / (Math.Pow(height, 2));  
        result.Text = Convert.ToString(MBICalc);
 ;
    }

   
    // Blocking enter letters

    private void heightBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            char number = e.KeyChar;
            if (e.KeyChar <= 47 || e.KeyChar >= 58)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }

        private void weightBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            char number = e.KeyChar;
            if (e.KeyChar <= 47 || e.KeyChar >= 58)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вместо `Convert.ToString` наверняка можно использовать `String.Format` и указать там формат строки и задать там сколько нужно знаков после запятой.

Comment: [Format types in .NET](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/formatting-types). И по ссылкам смотрите Standard numeric format strings, Custom numeric format strings.

Answer (score 0):

Для выполнения округления в c# есть метод `Math.Round`. Чтобы округлить до конкретного знака после запятой, можно использовать перегрузку этого метода, в которой в качестве второго аргумента нужно указать число знаков после запятой. Например, в вашем коде при установке значения в `TextBox` это будет выглядеть так:

```cs
result.Text = Convert.ToString(Math.Round(MBICalc, 1));//Где 1 означает 1 знак после запятой
```

Answer (score 0):

1. 

```
result.Text = $"{MBICalc:F2}";
```

2. 

```
result.Text = MBICalc.ToString("N2");
```

3. 

```
result.Text = Math.Round(MBICalc, 2).ToString();
```

4.Округление в ту или иную сторону

```
result.Text = Math.Round(inputValue, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

Comment: F2? N2? почему разные форматы?

Comment: @aepot одинаково сработают оба варианта. Про разницу между ними не уверен https://dotnetfiddle.net/mm6XIp

Comment: Но тогда почему вы в одном случае один используете, а во втором - другой?

Comment: Потому что никогда не задумывался о значениях символов N и F и принимал их просто как должное) А то что они одинаково работают в обеих случаях узнал вообще только сейчас :D